# interface function declarations to be used internally

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, contract-development, contract-design, remix

Is it possible to use externally declared interface functions internally in a smart contract? 
 i.e. say **contract A** inherits **interface A**, would **contract A** be able to implement the functions from **interface A** in an internal fashion (declaring a function as internal) not allowing the public to call it?

Comment: What's the point in declaring a function in the interface if no one except for other functions in the same contract can call it???

Answer (score 2):

An interface cannot contain functions declared as internal or public, only as external.

If you can declare your interface as contract and will not have that limitation.

```
contract Bob {
    function foo() internal;
}


contract Mar is Bob {

    function vote() public {
        foo();
    }

    function foo() internal {
    }
}
```

Comment: Just to clarify: "if you can declare your interface as abstract contract..."

Comment: it serves the same purpose in the end right? whether I declare as interface or abstract contract --> a layer of abstraction/compliance etc.

Comment: You use interfaces in some situations, for example to write an EIP or you have to integrate two separate applications. You do not have to use it if you do not need it.